# I Am Trying To Use Mariadb through python

Tags: mysql, python-3.7, mariadb-10.4

**This code is For mysql. But Mysql Does not work in my laptop so i opted for mariadb .
Can Someone help Me Out**

**I Also Installed MariaDB Connector/Python But No Use...**

````
try :
    conn = sql.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', passwd = 'darknessroot')
    if conn.is_connected:
        print('Connection......OK......')
    else:
        print('Connection......NOT OK......')
except:
    print('ERROR.... CHECK CONNECTION')```
````

Comment: host is an IP address only. Print the exception thrown, not just 'error'

Comment: okay let me that